# Find the angle θ (all the circles are tangent)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, angle, tangent-line

In the following figure ABCD is a side square $\alpha$, the points $P_0, P_1, P_2, P_3, Q_0, Q_1, Q_2, Q_3, X \ and \ Y$ are points of tangency, $BC \ and \ ZB$ are the diameters, respectively, of the blue and green semi-circles. Determine the angle $\theta$
Answer:$θ=67,5°$

There is a lot of homoteties, but I only could find that LK=$\frac{\sqrtα}{4}$. I guess that $BP_1$ are diagonal of the square, but I don't know how to prove (or disprove) this.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks for antetion. [image][Question image]

Comment: Yes, showing $P_1$ is on the diagonal would give us the answer.  I have no idea why the green semicircle is needed here.  I'd start by inverting in $C$ to determine circle $XP_0Q_0$ and hence $P_1$, but I suspect a nicer method exists.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $\angle P_1BC=\phi=180^\circ-2\theta$.

Next, let's find $r_0$ and $r_1$.

\begin{align}
\triangle LO_0E:&
\\
|O_0L|&=r+r_0=\tfrac a2+r_0
,\quad
|LE|=\tfrac a2-r_0
,\\
|O_0E|=|BX|&=
\sqrt{2 a r_0}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\triangle BO_0X:&
\\
|BO_0|&=R-r_0=a-r_0
,\quad
|O_0X|=r_0
,\\
|BX|&=\sqrt{a^2-2 a r_0}
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Since \eqref{1}=\eqref{2},
we have

\begin{align} 
r_0&=\frac a4
.
\end{align}

By Descartes' theorem
for four mutually tangent circles
with radii $R,r,r_0$ and $r_1$,

\begin{align} 
r_1&=
\left(
\tfrac1r+\tfrac1{r_0}-\tfrac1R
+2\sqrt{\tfrac1{r r_0}-\tfrac1{r R}-\tfrac1{r_0 R}}
\right)^{-1}
\\
&=
\frac{5-2\sqrt2}{17}\,a
.
\end{align}

Now, consider a Steiner’s chain of circles
with two reference circles: external,
centered at $B$ with radius $R=a$
and internal, with the center at $L$ and the radius $r=\tfrac a2$,
and known distance between the centers, $d=|BL|=r=\tfrac a2$.

Ignoring all the rest, let's assume that
the circle $O_1$ with already known radius $r_1$,
is the first in this Steiner’s chain of circles.
Then we can exploit a known formula to find the angle $\phi$:

\begin{align} 
r_1&=R-\tfrac12\,\frac{(r+R)^2-d^2}{r+R-d\,\cos\phi}
,\\
\cos\phi&=
\frac{a-3r_1}{a-r_1}
=
\frac{a-3\frac{5-2\sqrt2}{17}\,a}{a-\frac{5-2\sqrt2}{17}\,a}
=\frac{\sqrt2}2
,
\end{align}

and the answer follows.

---

**Edit**

Alternatively,
the same result can be obtained
much simpler:
since all of the sides of $\triangle BLO_1$ are known,
we can just use the cosine law:

\begin{align}
\cos\phi&=
\frac{|BO_1|^2+|BL|^2-|LO_1|^2}{2\cdot|BO_1|\cdot|BL|}
=
\frac{(R-r_1)^2+\tfrac{a^2}4-(r-r_1)^2}{2(R-r_1)^2\cdot\tfrac{a^2}4}
=\tfrac{\sqrt2}2
.
\end{align}